# From Array into Array to Range

Tags: arrays, vba, excel

I Created a `TempTable` as `ReDim TempTable(1 To RowSize, 1 To 3)`, for each cell I've a vector of 55 value. See image below to better understand

[image]

Now I'd like to copy the entire content of `TempTable` in my worksheet. The range should be [7576x55, 3] since `TempTable` has 7576 rows. Is there any smart and fast way to do that?

Comment: Create a new 2D array of the appropriate size; then loop through your original array and populate it.  Possibly `DIM V(1 to 7576, 1 to 3*55)`.  Then set R = R(7576,165)  and R.Value = V

Comment: `Dim tmpTBL as variant: tmpTBL = Range("A1:BC7576").Value2: Debug.Print LBound(tmpTBL, 1) & ":" & UBound(tmpTBL, 1): Debug.Print LBound(tmpTBL, 2) & ":" & UBound(tmpTBL, 2)`. I don't understand what you want to do with the 55 (... or 3?) values.

Comment: @Jeeped I need to paste them into a worksheet. Ideally I need to take TempTable(1,1) copy to A1:A55, then tahe TempTable(1,2) and copy to B1:B5, then TempTable(1,3) to C1:C55. Now shift down and stack so, TempTable(2,1) to A56:A111, TempTable(2,2) to B56:B111, etc.

Comment: Both arrays and worksheets can handle 1,048,576 rows. Why the third dimension to the array?

Comment: Since I copy data 55 by 55. Is there a way to assign a selection of 55 to the first 55 rows of an array and not put them in the 3rd dimension? (I used to manage 3d matrix in matlab but was much more easier, so i'm biased)

Comment: @gmeroni : Did you try my proposition?

Comment: @R3uK: I tried but wasn't getting the data in the way i liked. I ended up rewrinting the whole process and get a Temp Table of the right dimensions at the first population. See here the code: http://stackoverflow.com/a/34398976/2349516

Comment: @gmeroni : If my code worked for your initial issue, please accept the answer to mark your question as answered! ;)

Answer (score 1):

This should work smoothly (if the vectors in each column have the same size) :

```
Sub test_gmeroni()
Dim TempTable() As Variant, _
    wS As Worksheet, _
    Rg As Range, _
    InBound As Long, _
    i As Long, _
    j As Long

Set wS = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("OutPut")
Set Rg = wS.Range("A1")
ReDim TempTable(1 To 7576, 1 To 3)

For i = LBound(TempTable, 1) To UBound(TempTable, 1)
    For j = LBound(TempTable, 2) To UBound(TempTable, 2)
        'Calculate vectors size
        InBound = UBound(TempTable(i, j), 1)
        'Put vector on sheet
        Rg.Offset(0, j - 1).Resize(InBound, 1).Value2 = TempTable(i, j)
    Next j
    'Select next cell to start printing next row
    Set Rg = Rg.Offset(InBound + 1, 0)
Next i

End Sub
```